# NullPointer Exception error On Android/SQLITE aplication

Tags: android, sqlite

So, I'm working on an app that's supposed to play videos from the "\sdcard\movies",and to do that it has to consult a table on my database. However, the select query returns a nullpointer exception on the line:

```java
Cursor query = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT Arquivo FROM Comercial ORDER BY UltimaExecucao ASC , Random DESC LIMIT 1 ", null);
```

this is my code:

**DBHandler.java**

```java
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "/sdcard/movies/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "audiostore.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;

    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {

        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public String getData() {
        String str = new String();
        Cursor query = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT Arquivo FROM Comercial ORDER BY UltimaExecucao ASC , Random DESC LIMIT 1 ", null);
        str = query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(str));

        return str;

    }
}
```

Somebody can tell me why is it getting a null value?

**=====EDIT=====**

Here's the logcat:

```java
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity     ComponentInfo{com.sample.VideoViewExample/com.sample.VideoViewExample.VideoViewExample}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at com.sample.VideoViewExample.DBHandler.getData(DBHandler.java:158)
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at com.sample.VideoViewExample.VideoViewExample.onCreate(VideoViewExample.java:21)
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  ... 11 more
```

Where:

> 10-02 21:19:50.004: E/AndroidRuntime(507):  at com.sample.VideoViewExample.VideoViewExample.onCreate(VideoViewExample.java:21)

Is another class where the method should return the value of the cursor.

Comment: Please attach logcat stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never calling `openDataBase` method, so `myDataBase` object is `null` when execution reach line.-

```
Cursor query = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT Arquivo FROM Comercial ORDER BY UltimaExecucao ASC , Random DESC LIMIT 1 ", null);
```

Throwing the `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Your never actually opening the database. Your checkDatabase function opens it and closes it to check to see if it exists or not but you never actually open it so you can use it.

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
       //****This is where you need to open it*****
       myDataBase = openDataBase();
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}
```